# Android: How to setup ActionBar correctly with API level 11 or upper?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

I am trying to add an ActionBar with some menu items inside. I am using API version 11 and the app theme is Theme.Holo.Light:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication2.app" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myapplication2.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

menu/main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="HIhi"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_compose"
        android:title="hello" />
</menu>
```

My build.gardle setup is this which showing I am using min API version 11:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

But when I launch the app, the ActionBar is still on the bottom:

[image]

I was expecting the ActionBar will be shown up on the top right corner of the app (with 3 dots as collapse menu). Did I miss anything in my setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parameter android:showAsAction="Always" for each menu item in menu.xml to show your items in action bars

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_add_size"
        android:title="@string/menu_add_item"
        android:orderInCategory="10"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />
</menu>
```

And you have to remember: Android action bar menu view depends of device hardware control buttons type

**EDIT**
Just read [this](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/compatibility.html) article to understand differences, enjoy!

P.S. Sorry for my bad english :-(

Comment: Thanks, it works! So do you mean there is no way to make it to have a overflow button by default?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, to get your options to show in the action bar, you can use `android:showAsAction="always"` or (the better solution) you can use `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` and that way, it will only be in the action bar if it can fit.

So your `menu/main.xml` would be this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="HIhi"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_compose"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="hello" />
</menu>
```

However, this will not create the three vertical dots you describe. To do that, you can use a hack with this code:

```
public void getOverflowMenu()
{
    try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if(menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // ignore
    }
}
```

And then just call that method in your `onCreate` method like so:

```
getOverflowMenu();
```

I don't think this works on *all* devices. I seem to remember this hack not working on an Android 2.2 device, but that could just be bad memory.

Answer (score 1):

Govtart is generally right, but I can see that you have dependency on appcompat-v7 library. So you should use another namespace for actionbar-specific attributes:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />
    ...
</menu>
```

I used 'ifRoom' instead of 'always' as this is preferred option.

Comment: Yeah, I always don't know why I have appcompat-v7 lib dependency; Android Studio add that in the build.gradle when I created the project. Do know know why?

Comment: It is needed when you want to use features that were added in later API than your minSdkLevel. Action bar was added in Honeycomb, so you have to use appcompat if you want  to use Action bar and want to support earlier API.

Answer (score 0):

in your **menu/main.xml:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:id="@+id/settings"
     android:title="@string/settings"
     android:orderInCategory="0"
     android:showAsAction="always"
      />

  <item android:id="@+id/action_compose"
     android:title="hello"
     android:orderInCategory="1"
     android:showAsAction="always"
      />

</menu>
```

and in your **MainActivity** class you have to call the *onCreateOptionsMenu* function

```
   @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // action when action_search was selected
    case R.id.action_search:
      //****do something when the action_search item is clicked
      break;
    // action when action_compose was selected
    case R.id.action_compose:
      //****do something when the action_compose item is clicked
      break;

    default:
      break;
    }

    return true;
}
```